# Mind map in Mathematica

Tags: graphics

Are there (Mathematica 12) any built-in functionalities to create mind map diagrams like those found here

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/

or here

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485600/mindmap-diagram-in-beamer

?

Thanks.

For the sake of clarity I include below the image of the second link.

[image]

Comment: It's a kind of graph. Just so you know, if you have a question like "is there a function for...", feel free to ask this in the chat room if you want to.

Comment: Close to duplicate of: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197463/13